# Iterator over binary file

Tags: java, file, object, iterator, overwrite

**Hello everyone**
I wanted to know how to iterate on a file.
The iterator should support the options-

1. Upload to the map<String, Car> .
2. Allow removal of the last Car including its ID which is represented in String.
   Without using an auxiliary array or auxiliary file, i.e. tampering with the file itself only.
   Some of the ideas I came up with were to use random access file and seek to the last place, I mean it will work together with ObjectInputStream.

*How to do Remove?*

This is what I have so far, I would like to get guidance:

```
 public class MyFile implements Iterable<Car> {
    private Map<String,Car> allCars;
    final String fileName;
    

    public MyFile(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Car> iterator() {
        return new MyFileIterator();
    }

    class MyFileIterator implements Iterator<Car> {
        private ObjectOutputStream oOut;
        private ObjectInputStream oIn;
        //BufferedReader in;
        //String nextline;
        Car nextCar;
        String nexrID;
        int position;

        public MyFileIterator() {
            oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName, true)); 
            oIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        }

        // If the file isn't over
        public boolean hasNext() { 
          return oIn.available() != 0;
        }

        // Return the next Car
        public Car next() {
            nextID = oIn.readUTF();
            nextCar = (Car)oIn.readObject();
            
            return nextCar;
        }
//TODO:
        public void remove() { 
            
                    
            }
      }
```

Comment: What is the problem? If there is an error or exception, please let us know what it is. If you don't get the right output, please show us the input, the actual output, and the expected output. If the code is correct, this is the wrong place for this.

Comment: I want to know how to do remove of the last String and Object that written in the file.

Comment: Serialization via `ObjectOutputStream` does not produce a format that is intended for direct manipulation like this: it contains back-references and other features that make it very tricky to manipulate it in-place. It's meant as a stream that's either written or read as a whole (or read from the beginning up to some point), but not accessed randomly. Other serialization formats might support this feature.

Comment: @JoachimSauer 

Hi, thank you for your answer .. 
When you say Other serialization formats, what do you actually offer?
I can do this with random access file. But that would require reading a field-field every time I thought there would be an easier way with an ObjectStream.